# tink_core Future (haxe) form c++

Tags: c++, c++11, future

In haxe there is a library called [tink core](https://github.com/haxetink/tink_core) which supplies so called "[Futures](https://github.com/haxetink/tink_core#future)".

A Future is a value, that is not yet calculated (the result of an asynchronous operation for example).

Among other things, I can do the following things with a Future:

- call map with a function that modifies the value, to create a new future with the modified value
- call first with two futures, to create a new future with the value of the future that finishes first
- Add a callback to the future, that will be called when the value is available.

Now in C++ there is [std::future](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), but I do not see that the operations described above are possible with it.

Also, it seems that std::future can only be created with std::async. But I want to create futures in my own way, without a function callback.

So my question:

- Am I misjudging std::future, and it can do all of this?
- Is there a different future library in c++ I have not found and that can do this?

Comment: I am no haskell expert but Bartosz Milewski addresses some issues he has with std::future compared to haskell. Maybe [this](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/02/26/c17-i-see-a-monad-in-your-future/) helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main mistaken assumption is that only `std::aysnc` creates a `std::future`. In fact, `std::promise` and `std::packaged_task` do the same.

The first of your three operations (mapping) is fairly simple. You basically want `G(F(x))`. This requires a new `packaged_task` which takes the first future, waits for its result, and then calls the function `G()` on `F(x)`

The second operation is inefficient in Standard C++ as there's no efficient multi-wait. You'd have to poll both futures. In comparison, Windows has `WaitForMultipleObjects()`.

The third is essentially a variant of the first as it's basically `f=F(X);G(f); return f` - call `G` once `F(X)` has returned but ignore the return value of `G` and use the original return value from `F(X)`.